# Exclude a product from WooCommerce Booking Google calendar sync in unpaid status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, google-calendar-api, woocommerce-bookings

I have an issue with excluding 1 product from woocommerce bookings Google calendar sync in unpaid status. I have a clients which are booking individual classes where they pay at. These classes I need to sync with my google calendar in unpaid status. 1 product is for more people and each of them have to pay before the lesson starts. I would like to sync these bookings once they are paid into my calendar.

I use this code to get unpaid bookings to my google calendar.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_booking_is_paid_statuses', 'woocommerce_booking_add_unpaid_to_is_paid_statuses');
function woocommerce_booking_add_unpaid_to_is_paid_statuses( $statuses ) { 
$statuses[]= 'unpaid';
return $statuses;
}
```

I need to exclude product id 946 from this function. Could you please give me some advice how to do it? Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I've tried to modify function like this, but I'm still getting some error in wp.

Code

```
function woocommerce_bookings_kalendar( $statuses, $order ) { 
// Get items in order
    $items = $order->get_items(); 

// Loop for all items
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
       $product_id = $item['product_id'];

if ( $product_id == 946 ) {
            $statuses[]= 'unpaid';

return $statuses;
}
}
}
add_filter('woocommerce_booking_is_paid_statuses', 'woocommerce_bookings_kalendar');
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function woocommerce_bookings_kalendar()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update 2

To avoid *"Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments: …"* error, should need **to declare the number of hook arguments *(variables)***, when there are more than one, in the `add_filter()` function like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_booking_is_paid_statuses', 'filter_booking_is_paid_statuses', 10, 2 );
function filter_booking_is_paid_statuses( $statuses, $order ) { 
    // Do something

    return $statuses;
}
```

This will solve this error.

> **But** the hook `woocommerce_booking_is_paid_statuses`, located in `includes/class-wc-bookings-google-calendar-connection.php` file of WooCommerce booking plugin and **has a unique variable argument `$statuses`**.
>
> So in your code `$order` will be always `null` and `$items = $order->get_items();` will **throw another error**.

So it's not possible to get order details using this hook.

---

To exclude specific unpaid booking from WooCommerce Booking Google calendar sync, you could try to use additionally `woocommerce_bookings_gcalendar_sync` filter hook.

So your code replacement will be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_booking_is_paid_statuses', 'filter_booking_is_paid_statuses' );
function filter_booking_is_paid_statuses( $statuses ) { 
    return array_merge( $statuses, array('unpaid') );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_bookings_gcalendar_sync', 'filter_bookings_gcalendar_sync', 10, 2 );
function filter_booking_has_status( $event, $booking ){
    $excl_product_id = 946;

    if( $booking->get_status() === 'unpaid' && $booking->get_product_id() !== $excl_product_id ) {
        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(); // Get an empty event Object
        $event->setid( $booking->get_google_calendar_event_id() ); // Set Id
    }
    return $event;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Untested it could work.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply :) I very appreciate your answer. I have put this code into my child theme, but Im getting this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null. Any idea why?

Comment: This error is happening when I update date manually. For example my client calls me to change its time and then this happens.

Comment: @LuboMasura I don't use the method `getId()` on my code, so this error is due to some other code you have added. Try to remove all other related code customizations.

Comment: That error is getting from google calendar sync, when this code is out that error does not shows up. Strange.  I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you anyway Loic :)

Comment: thank you for your update, it did not help still getting that error when I update date.

Comment: Where can I send you error details? Maybe we are doing it wrong.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h3qrd1p7/ -this is what I get from my site.

Comment: Try to clean up (delete) older comments. You can add an edit at the end of your question, and notify me here… But I am just trying to guess things as I don't test anything... So if it doesn't work, I don't have anymore clue.